# Does Xcode have a keyboard shortcut/binding that functions like "Delete to Word End" in IntelliJ?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut in Xcode that will behave like IntelliJ's "Delete to Word End". I essentially want Option + Delete to delete:

- One brace (if to the right of it)
- One parenthesis (if to the right of it)
- A variable/function name, or any word (including the whitespace to the right of it if whitespace is between the word and the cursor)

I think this may have to do with the differentiation between a word and a WORD in vim, but I'm not sure, and I don't know if Xcode makes that differentiation at all.

For example, in IntelliJ, when I press Option + Delete (⌥⌫), "Delete to Word End" (the default) is triggered. Referring to the code example at the end of this post, multiple uses of this shortcut would delete, in order:

1. The closing brace
2. The rest of the whitespace on the line (placing cursor at beginning of line)
3. The newline (placing cursor one tab deeper than the function definition)
4. The whitespace on that line (placing cursor at beginning of line)
5. The newline (placing cursor to right of opening brace)
6. The opening brace

However, with the same starting cursor position in Xcode, one press of Option + Delete (currently bound to "Delete Word Forward" and "Delete Word Backward" by default) will delete both braces, both parentheses, AND the function name (in this example, "display").

I tried playing with the "Delete"-related keybindings in Xcode to find a similar functionality, but to no avail. Is this just a convenient feature IntelliJ has, or is there a way to duplicate this in Xcode that I'm missing?

Example function (cursor positioned at ^):

```
func display() {

}^
```